# Swing draw string centeralised

Tags: java, swing

I have to draw n + 1 amount of circles horizontally and vertically in a GUI. Which I have successfully done as shown below. With this, a 2D array of strings will be printed between them, centralised.

How it currently stands

[image]

Now I want to draw numbers in a "square" of the dots.

How I want the final result

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        canvas.drawCircle( (j + 1) * 125, (i + 1) * 125, 15, Color.white);
    }
}

for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
        canvas.drawString(events[r][c], (r + 1) * 150, (c + 1) * 150, Color.green );
    }
}
```

Width in this case is 4, so basically (n-1) dots/circles in the picture.

Size is 3 which is just the length of the 2d array, as there are 4 circles in this case there will be 3 numbers between each one

Events is the 2D array with the data containing the numbers

The drawCircle method's signature is 
    (x, y, radius, color)

The drawString method's signature is
    (text, x, y color)

I believe part of the problem is also the drawing of circles. Basically I think it has to do with the rubbish formula I have for determining the x, y coords for both circles and the text. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided is some code which I believe does what you want. Some of the constants may be tweaked to fit your final requirements. I used a 2D array of numbers and converted to strings during paint. It also allows for the following:

- Changing the ball diameter or number of balls will still provide a
  correct graph (although it will change its location within the
  panel).
- The String numbers track along with the size of the balls
- Anti-aliasing was turned on to smooth out the graphics.
- FontMetrics was used to fine tune the location of the numbers.

One final note:  Because this is not resource intensive, the coordinates are calculated within the paintComponent method.  A more optimum solution would be to adopt the `Flyweight design pattern` and precalculate as much as possible before entering paintComponent.

```java
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class SwingMain extends JPanel {

       final static int WIDTH      = 700;
       final static int HEIGHT     = 700;
       final static int SEPARATION = 100;
       final static int DIAMETER   = 25;
       final static int NBALLS     = 4;
       final static int XSTART     = WIDTH / (NBALLS + 2);
       final static int YSTART     = HEIGHT / (NBALLS + 2);
       JFrame           frame      = new JFrame();
       int[][]          numbers    = new int[NBALLS - 1][NBALLS - 1];

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SwingMain().start());
       }

       public void start() {
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
          frame.add(this);
          setBackground(Color.RED);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          // populate numbers in 2D array.
          for (int r = 0; r < NBALLS - 1; r++) {
             for (int c = 0; c < NBALLS - 1; c++) {
                numbers[r][c] = r * (NBALLS - 1) + c + 1;
             }
          }
       }

       @Override
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

          // Allow smoothing of the graphics.
          g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
          g2d.setColor(Color.white);

          // Iterating by the number of balls is more consistent than
          // by x and y due to round of errors.

          int y = YSTART;
          for (int r = 0; r < NBALLS; r++) {
             int x = XSTART;
             for (int c = 0; c < NBALLS; c++) {
                g2d.fillOval(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
                x += SEPARATION;
             }
             y += SEPARATION;
          }

          // This is the same as above except that the start begins
          // halfway between the first row and column

          // have the size of the font track with the diameter of the balls
          g2d.setFont(new Font("ARIAL", Font.BOLD, DIAMETER));
          FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
          y = YSTART + SEPARATION / 2;
          for (int r = 0; r < NBALLS - 1; r++) {
             int x = XSTART + SEPARATION / 2;
             for (int c = 0; c < NBALLS - 1; c++) {
                String number = Integer.toString(numbers[r][c]);

                // Do some final position adjustment with the font metrics to
                // center the number

                int strWidth = fm.stringWidth(number);
                int strHeight = fm.getAscent();
                g2d.drawString(number,
                      x - strWidth / 2 + DIAMETER / 2,
                      y + strHeight);

                x += SEPARATION;
             }
             y += SEPARATION;
          }

       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the coordinates of the circles in a 2D array as well, and use that to find the location of the strings. One thing to note is that the `drawCircle` method for some reason wont draw the circle with the given center (the coordinates you give will be the top left corner actually).

```
Point[][] circleCoords = new Point[width][width]; //suppose Point class has x and y coords 

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    //the -15 actually centers the circle to the coordianates
    circleCoords[i][j] = new Point((j + 1) * 125 - 15, (i + 1) * 125 -15);
    canvas.drawCircle(circleCoords[i][j].x , circleCoords[i][j].y, 15, Color.white);
   }
}

for (int r = 0; r < width-1; r++) {
   for (int c = 0; c < width-1; c++) {
    //calculate coords from circleCoords array: halfway between them
    int xCoord = (circleCoords[r][c].x + circleCoords[r+1][c].x)/2; 
    int yCoord = (circleCoords[r][c].y + circleCoords[r][c+1].y)/2;
    //wont be out of bounds, becouse this runs to width-1
    canvas.drawString(events[r][c], xCoord, yCoord, Color.green );
    }
 }
```

This still wont actually be perfectly centered, because the drawString will use the coordinates for top left point as well, and not centerpoint. Maybe I miscalculated something, but this should give you the idea: instead of calculating the coordinates independently, re-use the circle coordinates.

Comment: I tried this solution and it centered the strings into the actual circle. Perhaps I did it wrong? Or maybe you misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a class that represents a single square. The value is represented by a `JLabel` which is placed at the bottom using straight-forward layout manager (`BorderLayout` in this example). You can change or manipulate the layout manager to change to position of the `JLabel`.

```
class Square extends JPanel{

    private static int WIDTH = 100, HEIGHT = 100, DAIMETER  = 30, GAP = 5;
    private final JLabel label;

    Square(int value) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setOpaque(true);
        label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(value), JLabel.RIGHT);
        label.setForeground (Color.white);
        Border margin = new EmptyBorder(GAP,GAP,GAP,2*GAP); //top left bottom right
        label.setBorder(margin);
        add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.fillOval(WIDTH/2 - DAIMETER/2, HEIGHT/2-DAIMETER/2, DAIMETER, DAIMETER);
    }
}
```

Now add 16 instances of this `Square` to panel representing a board. Its layout manager is set to `GridLayout`:

```
class Board extends JPanel{

    private static int ROWS = 4, COLS = 4;

    Board(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));

        for(int index = 0; index < ROWS * COLS; index ++){
            add(new Square(index)); //index is used as value for demonstration purposes 
        }
    }
}
```

Putting it all together (this is a one-file mcve. Copy paste the entire code into `SwingMain.java` and run )

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SwingMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(400,250);
        frame.add(new Board());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Board extends JPanel{

    private static int ROWS = 4, COLS = 4;

    Board(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));

        for(int index = 0; index < ROWS * COLS; index ++){
            add(new Square(index)); //index is used as value for demonstration purposes 
        }
    }
}

class Square extends JPanel{

    private static int WIDTH = 100, HEIGHT = 100, DAIMETER  = 30, GAP = 5;
    private final JLabel label;

    Square(int value) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setOpaque(true);
        label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(value), JLabel.RIGHT);
        label.setForeground (Color.white);
        Border margin = new EmptyBorder(GAP,GAP,GAP,2*GAP); //top left bottom right
        label.setBorder(margin);
        add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        g2d.fillOval(WIDTH/2 - DAIMETER/2, HEIGHT/2-DAIMETER/2, DAIMETER, DAIMETER);
    }
}
```

[image]